# Invoices for Printing in MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, layout, printing

The application that I'm currently working on has a funky set up for the invoices that they print.

The form *is* the invoice that is printed out. I took a look at the Northwind DB and what it does is and it actually generates a report based on the record's information.

What are the limitations of using Forms vs. Reports for printing out reports? One of the limitations that I've run into so far is that the printed page is jam packed with information (all required) to fit on a single page, yet there is lots of wasted space for some stuff since  elements on the page don't shrink or grow due to what's inputted into the textboxes.

How are invoices designed for your applications? How do you handle space restraints for creating invoices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reports are for printing, forms are for on-screen viewing and editing. I don't stray from this for anything permanent.

The invoices that I've created have all been reports.

Comment: Yep.  I'm not sure the customer needs to see big blocks with "Add", "Delete", "Print", "Next Record", and so on on their invoice.  And, a grayish background color on an invoice may be nice to some people, but it's also a waste of printer ink.  Scrollbars also aren't very much help on a hard-copy.

Comment: Many elements on the form don't show up for printing thanks to the 'Display When' property set to 'Screen Only'.

Comment: I really wish people who think they are professional Access developers would stencil that first clause on the insides of their eyelids. I've had to fix this problem way too many times, and just don't know what they were thinking. The ability to use forms and reports interchangeably for some things is one of those "features" that is of no real use in an actual application.